# Windows 8 Pro install on empty hard drive allowed?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 8 upgrade](https://superuser.com/questions/493122/windows-8-upgrade)

If I purchase the Windows 8 Pro copy via the [Windows 8 offer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/buy?ocid=GA8_O_WOL_DIS_ShopHP_FPP_Light) that's currently running until Jan 2013, do I *have* to install it on a PC having an existing installation of an eligible copy of Windows 7, or will it allow upgrading from a regular blank hard drive?

Also in the future if I need to reformat my PC, will I have to first install Windows 7, and then upgrade to Windows 8?

Comment: It has to be an upgrade from an eligible version. More information can be found on the below link

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the previous question, which was asking whether an update tied to someone else's new Windows 7 PC could be installed on a different PC.  This question is asking whether a copy of "Windows Pro Upgrade" can be installed on a bare hard-drive without first installing Windows 7 or Windows XP (which it can, see my answer).

Comment: @PJC - Actually it is, because this was answered in the other question, an upgrade copy of Windows 8 cannot be installed without a previous version of Windows ( XP, Vista, 7, 8 RP) being on the hdd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you have an eligible copy of Windows 7 or XP for upgrade, you do not need to pre-install Windows 7 (or XP).

Instead of validating your existing copy, you will need to enter your Windows 7 or XP license key as well as the Windows 8 upgrade key during the installation process.

Comment: do you have any references on this? or personally tried it?

Comment: @fmsf - The FAQ on the product's page, or really ANY retailer at this point, proves this is correct.

Comment: @Ramhound: As per [this thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_cp-windows_install/licensing-and-upgrading-multiple-computers-to/cdb8e967-4dce-483a-86e4-4f4065f57d0d), which I was linked to as an answer to [my question](http://superuser.com/questions/492619/using-the-same-windows-8-upgrade-installer-on-multiple-pcs), you *do* need to install the older version of Windows first. Now the answer above is contradicting it. Will *someone* positively confirm which is the correct answer once and for all?

Comment: @Karan I decided to go ahead try it out myself (after putting due backups in place), and found that you can indeed do a fresh install with nothing but the Windows 8 installation media on a blank hard drive. Also, the installation process *does not* ask for the Windows 7 key during install.

Comment: @kpax: Only problem is, from all reports I've read so far that type of clean install on a blank drive using the Upgrade version simply won't activate. Did you try to do so? What was the result? After all, if this were possible, why would anyone in their right mind pay for the costlier System Builder version?

Comment: @Karan Ok, I came across this link on the MS website - http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows-8/why-activate-windows - and apparently I should not have been able to install and activate, which it did. I'm totally confused now :(

Comment: @kpax: Actually, I am as well. :/ Apparently there have been reports from others too who have managed to replicate your good fortune. But it doesn't seem to be universal unfortunately. Maybe some glitch with the activation servers helped you out? :D

Comment: @Karan Great, so given Murphy's law, by the time I actually get around to installing Windows 8 as a daily driver, I will run into the activation roadblock being faced by most. Damn!

Answer (score 1):

This is only an Upgrade Version, you should have Windows XP SP3, Windows Vista or Windows 7 Pre installed to Upgrade.