# How to make a Windows 8 clean install without prior Windows installation or key?

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Windows 8 pro on a built PC](https://superuser.com/questions/492551/installing-windows-8-pro-on-a-built-pc)

I've been a Mac user for ages and I don't have any copy of Windows (xp, vista or 7). So I need to make a clean install on my custom built pc currently running Linux.

I have found some information regarding the existence of a "Windows 8 pro system builder" which will allow clean installs in blank disks without any pre-requisites for prior Windows versions, but all information is very vague and without references.

Does anyone know how to do this kind of installation?  Where can I buy the Windows 8 system builder?

Comment: I'm assuming clean Windows 8 is hard to come by for home use? I guess MSDN spoils me :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you will need to have your system boot with the System Builder DVD. This can be accomplished by changing the boot order in your BIOS (which can be accessed upon booting your system by pressing the prompted key that is labeled set-up). After you are able to successfully change the boot order, you only need to insert the DVD and follow the on-screen instructions. Note that System Builder will wipe your hard drive of all files, so it would be wise to make a backup before proceeding.

System Builder 64-bit can be found here: [link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0094NXBZ0)

Answer (score 6):

One option is to pop to the shops (or order online) a physical DVD. **You do want the system builder version**, Windows 8 Pro is upgrade only (confusingly!).

For example On amazon's US site: [Windows 8 Professional System Builder DVD 64-Bit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0094NXBZ0)

---

You might be tempted to brun a DVD from the RTM ISO with the view to buying a key later, so you can download it, however the evaluation version of windows 8 **will expire** ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/apps/br229516.aspx)) and can't be upgraded to retail.

> If you’re not an MSDN subscriber, you can download an evaluation version of Windows 8 from Evaluation Center . Note this version will expire and you cannot upgrade.

Comment: http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbpage.Windows_8_Pro says: "To install Windows 8 Pro, customers must be running Windows XP SP3, Windows Vista, or Windows 7" in the "shipped version"

Comment: Edited just as you were posting.

Comment: Aierou answered faster :P still +1

Answer (score 4):

The system builder licence has traditionally been used by small OEMs (e.g. your local computer builder). In the past, home users were not allowed to use it, and had to buy the more expensive retail licence.

However, with Windows 8, Microsoft [has changed their system builder licence to allow personal use](http://www.zdnet.com/microsoft-radically-overhauls-license-agreements-for-windows-8-7000002866/):

> a new license type called a Personal Use License for System Builder, which won’t be available until the General Availability of Windows 8 in October.
>
> This last type replaces the outmoded and overpriced full package product and represents a significant and positive change in the way Microsoft licenses Windows.

With this change, people who build their computers themselves get the same, cheaper price. The licences are not quite the same; the system builder licence requires the builder to support the end user and has distribution clauses, etc.. The personal use licence is reminiscent of the old full retail licence.

The new personal use licence can be found [here](http://personaluselicense.windows.com/en-US/default.aspx), the traditional OEM system builder licence can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/OEM/en/licensing/sblicensing/Pages/localized_licenses.aspx).

---

At least here in Australia, you can probably buy a personal use licence from one of the smaller computer stores: http://www.pcworld.idg.com.au/article/440191/windows_8_launches_australia_-_can_buy_full_version/

Comment: The author doesn't have a version to upgrade from, so the Windows 8 Pro, or Window 8 upgrade, won't work for him.  This means the system builder is their only option.  Besides `System Builder` is the only "stand-alone" product, i.e. to be used on new systems, that have no version of operating system.

Comment: @Ramhound *> However, this is definitely not suited for your purpose.* Perhaps I did not make that clear enough. I was just listing what Microsoft provides in that first section..

Comment: It only will confuse future readers.

Comment: @Ramhound Removed it. That better?

Comment: (I Am Not A Lawyer.)

Comment: You don't need to be a lawyer to understand the license and give good sound advice.

Comment: @Ramhound I still prefer to use the disclaimer, since this is my (uneducated in law) opinion. I recently remembered, and added it to my previous answers discussing Windows licensing, but this particular question was closed so I added a comment rather than bumping it.