# Buy Full Windows 8 not just an upgrade

Tags: windows, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does a full, retail license of Windows 8 exist? (Not OEM, not upgrade)](https://superuser.com/questions/494782/does-a-full-retail-license-of-windows-8-exist-not-oem-not-upgrade)

The official website of Windows says a price of $39.99 for online upgrade and a $69.99 for a DVD upgrade.

But I don't have any previous Windows installed. What option do I have?

**Updated**
If I get an upgrade than how will I re-install it in future if I need to format my system. Install XP again and than upgrade? Or directly install Windows 8?

Comment: You [need](http://superuser.com/questions/492551/installing-windows-8-pro-on-a-built-pc) the older OS installed to activate. Get the System Builder version if you don't want to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also, NewEgg has the full version of Windows 8 Pro

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16832416552

http://www.newegg.com/Operating-Systems/SubCategory/ID-368

Answer (score 3):

You can download a Windows 7 iso, and install it (without authentication). I think they allow you like 30 days? from there you can use the upgrade adviser to download/install Windows 8, I suggest either putting the media on a USB flash drive, or a DVD.

You can legitimately get the ISOs from [here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/download-windows-7-iso-official-32-bit-and-64-bit-direct-download-links/)

Comment: 30 days in Win 7 (no similar grace period in Win8 though), plus multiple rearms up to 120 days total evaluation time I believe.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have Windows pre-installed then you need to get the regular Windows 8 DVD.

Comment: That must be region specific ?

Comment: It states right on the site "You can download an upgrade to Windows 8 Pro for your PC ***running Windows 7, Windows Vista, or Windows XP with Service Pack 3 (SP3)*** for an estimated retail price (ERP) of $39.99." Key work is "running". The installer looks for an installed version.

Comment: No, DVD update also requires an already installed version of Windows. If there's no installed Windows version, it has nothing to Upgrade.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov it doesn't need anything to upgrade, you can do a clean install with the upgrade media...the "hard part" if you will is getting the media... once you get the media you can put it anywhere you want (with or without) a previous install. Or at least that is how it has been in the past.

Comment: No, you need to have an installed version on HDD before starting upgrade. You can reformat the drive after the installer validated the previous version of Windows. [Clean Install Windows 8 with Upgrade Media](http://www.winsupersite.com/article/windows8/clean-install-windows-8-upgrade-media-144648) explains it step by step.

Comment: I think you guys are talking past each other. One of you is talking about an upgrade *license* (which requires a previous *license* to upgrade) and the other is talking about an upgrade *installation* (which requires a previous *installation* to upgrade).